# How to ignore NULL values and only print true values?

Tags: sqlite

I'm new to SQL so I'm trying to learn it by creating a simple login page, I have in the database 3 users and I'm trying to make SQLite return true if it finds a match and nothing if it finds NULL.

This is the table called "users".

```
ID          username    password    recovery
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------- 
1           Admin       pass         476 
2           mod         pass123      928      
3           test001     12345        182
```

This code works but it returns both NULL and true:

```
select case when username in ('mod') 
AND password = ('pass123') then true
else NULL end from users
```

What it does:

```
1    NULL
2    2
3    NULL
```

What I need it to do:

```
1   2
```

I tried many things like LIMIT and ORDER but I can't figure it out, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to get `1` meaning `true` and `2` for the `id` of the row that contains the user's data.
You don't need the `CASE` statement but a condition in the `WHERE` clause. 
Also no need for the `LIKE` operator because you check for equality.
So do this:

```
select true, id 
from users 
where username = 'mod' and password = 'pass123'
```

Comment: the "id" is just a row that i get from the result, its not an actual column like "username" and "password"

Removing "id" from your code makes it return as I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With the current code that you have, you are selecting all the records in the database

```
ID          username    password    recovery
----------  ----------  ----------  ---------- 
1           Admin       pass         476 
2           mod         pass123      928      
3           test001     12345        182
```

and then transforming them into a single column, showing true or null depending on the username and password values. That's what you are getting because of what's in your SELECT clause.

What you want to do is:

- add a WHERE clause, to actually select the record that you want (username=whatever and password=whatever)
- in the SELECT clause, show the ID of the record (not sure if you want true or the ID but as per your example of what you wanted, it was suggested that you wanted the ID of the record), therefore SELECT ID
- possibly limiting the resultset to a single record, if yes, add a LIMIT clause (LIMIT 1)